# Where can I download the Visual Studio 2012 Report Viewer Runtime?

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2012

Now that Visual Studio 2012 is released, where can I download the accompanying 2012 Report Viewer Runtime so I can install it on my server? Is there a redistributable installer included with Visual Studio 2012?

Specifically, I'm looking for the updated 2012 version of this: [Microsoft Report Viewer 2010 Redistributable Package](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6442)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

the final version of the installation program is http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35747

Comment: Without SQL Server 2012 installed, this download requires the  “Microsoft System **CLR Types for SQL Server® 2012**, you can download that (either x86 or x64 from this answer: http://serverfault.com/a/471782/43110

Answer (score 16):

I believe I've found a temporary workaround for this:

1. In your project's references, select the Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms assembly.
2. Add a reference to `C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common\11.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll`
3. In the properties window, set "Copy Local" to True for both assemblies.
4. Deploy your project to the server.

I haven't tested this extensively, but so far it appears that simply copying the assembly to your project's bin directory satisfies the runtime requirements on the server.

Comment: I also think you need top copy the other DLLs from the GAC into the bin folder... Specifically Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel.dll Microsoft.ReportViewer.DataVisualization.DLL and Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll

Comment: @MikeG Thanks for this additional detail. I had only tested what was necessary for my own application as a stop-gap until Microsoft released the redistributable, which it appears they have done: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13764780/85196